# Can you check if a Type (not an instance) is a subclass of another Type?

Tags: swift, types, casting

Given this code...

```
class Vehicle{}

class Car : Vehicle {}

class Honda : Car {}
```

How would you write the function 'findFirst' below...

```
class TypeManager {

    var managedTypes:[Any.Type]?

    func findFirst(_ type:Any.Type) -> Any.Type? {
        return managedTypes.first{ t in t is type.Type } // <-- Doesn't like 'type'
    }
}

var typeManager = TypeManager()
typeManager.managedTypes = [
    String.self,
    Int.self,
    Honda.self
]

let firstCarType = typeManager.findFirst(Car.Type)
```

Note: This is actually doing a reverse-key-lookup on a dictionary.  In a perfect solution, I'd first try finding an exact match on 'type', and if not found, settle for a subclass of 'type'.  I just simplified the (faked) code to focus on the matching portion.

Comment: Could you please give a single example how this could be used?

Comment: I'm searching through a list of Types (not instances) looking for any that match the requirement of being a direct match or a subclass of a given type. This is trivial in C# using `CanAssignFrom`.

Comment: Updated the q with a little more of an example.

Comment: What about `first(where: { $0 is Foo.Type  })` ?

Comment: I thought `is` only checks instances.

Comment: I appreciate your comment 'don't see how this could be useful', but that's out of the scope of this.  This is trivial in other languages. Just wondering how it's done here in Swift, if at all.

Comment: Martin... I missed you said '.Type'.  That was it!

Comment: Classes are also instances (of a meta-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon [Martin R's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59849459/409958) you can make an array extension like the following:

```swift
extension Array {
    func first<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T.Type?  {
        return first { $0 is T.Type } as? T.Type
    }
    func first<T>(ofExactType type: T.Type) -> T.Type? {
        return first { $0 as? Any.Type == type } as? T.Type
    }
}

class Vehicle {}
class Car : Vehicle {}
class Honda: Car {}

let carTypes = [Honda.self, Vehicle.self, Car.self] // Inferred type [Vehicle]
print(carTypes.first(ofType: Car.self) ?? "n/a") // prints Honda
print(carTypes.first(ofExactType: Car.self) ?? "n/a") // prints Car
```

Also, just FYI, `$0 as? Any.Type == type` is the same as doing `$0 as? Any.Type == T.self`. Either one would work.

Comment: Perfect!  Technically @Martin got it first, but he put it in the comments so I couldn't accept that! lol!

Comment: He sure did; great question, too

Comment: Damn! Gotta pull this back.  Lemme update my question with a little more that missed an important part.  Sorry! :/

Comment: I'm struggling now with being able to pass the type into a function rather than hard-coding like it is here.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What are the desired parameter and return types of the function?

Comment: This is getting so good! :) Question... same one I had for Martin... what if I wanted an exact match on T, not just a subclass? Tried both '==' and '===' but neither worked. The reason I'm asking is this is actually a reverse-key-lookup in a dictionary where one key may be for the value 'Car' but another key is for the value 'Honda'. If I wanted the key for 'Car', not 'Honda', I'd need an exact match on 'Car' only.

Comment: `==` should work. Changed up my answer using an extension

Comment: Voted this up!  Awesome!!!  You *do* use the passed-in value when you want an exact match. If you want a subclass, you use the inferred T.  Just awesome!  I love days like this!  And actually, I'm gonna switch the answer back to you.  He's got 444k.  He won't miss the 10 points! haha!

Comment: just updated to make the extension apply to all types of arrays not just `[Any.Type]` arrays

Answer (score 1):

Classes are instances of a meta-type and can be checked with `is` and `as?`.
You can use a generic function to pass in the sought type:

```
class TypeManager {

    var managedTypes:[Any.Type] = []

    func findFirst<T>(_: T.Type) -> Any.Type? {
        return managedTypes.first { $0 is T.Type }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if let firstCarType = typeManager.findFirst(Car.self) {
    print(firstCarType) // Honda
}
```

Or with conditional binding and compactMap:

```
class TypeManager {

    var managedTypes:[Any.Type] = []

    func findFirst<T>(_: T.Type) -> T.Type? {
        return managedTypes.compactMap { $0 as? T.Type }.first
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that the returned type is `T.Type?` and not `Any.Type?`. (Use `managedTypes.lazy.compactMap` if the list can be large and short circuiting is wanted.)

Comment: Aaaah!  A generic!  Man, didn't even think of that, but that's it, perfectly! (Prolly why you're at 444k!!! lol)

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't actually use 'type' here. You're only using it to type the generic 'T', then it's simply ignored, correct?

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe: You are right (so that the internal name `type` is actually not needed). The compiler infers `T` from the context (e.g. `Car`) and that is passed to the function.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if I wanted an *exact* match on T, not just a subclass? Tried both '==' and '===' but neither worked. The reason I'm asking is this is actually a reverse-key-lookup in a dictionary where one key may be for the value 'Car' but another key is for the value 'Honda'.  If I wanted the key for 'Car', not 'Honda', I'd need an exact match.